# Sorting upper and lower case words in vector of strings

Tags: c++, sorting, alphabetical

I'm trying to alphabetize words in a vector of strings and my program is distinguishing between upper and lowercase letters, so uppercase words always appear first in the sorted list. I can think of potentially really cumbersome ways to make sure the upper case words go in their place, but is there a simple way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < str.size(); j++) 
        {
            if (str.at(i) > str.at(j))
            {               
                temp = str.at(j);
                str.at(j) = str.at(i);
                str.at(i) = temp;
            }   
        }
    }
```

Also, this is for a programming assignment, so I am not allowed to use built in C++ functions to do this and I have to use a vector.

Comment: Is it acceptable to use `std::sort()` with a custom greater than function??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick to solving this is to write a replacement for this line

```
if (str.at(i) > str.at(j))
```

that performs case-insensitive comparison. Start by writing a signature for it:

```
bool greaterThanIgnoreCase(const string& left, const string& right) {
    ...
}
```

Now you can replace your `if` condition with a call to this new function:

```
if (greaterThanIgnoreCase(str.at(i), str.at(j)))
```

Finally, you need to provide an implementation of `greaterThanIgnoreCase` function. This is the core of the problem, so you would need to do it yourself. The trick to it is using [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) or [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) function on each character of strings `left` and `right`, and compare them one character at a time. If you run out of characters in one of the strings, the one with some characters remaining should be considered greater.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `vector` of `string`s then you could/should use the STL library, which offers `sort` or `stable_sort` for a given comparison function (that can be a simple lambda expression, functor, function,...).

Update: You're not allowed to use built-in types except vector.
In this case you can develop easily a replicate of what STL does.

Define a sort function that receives a comparator (for a vector of strings).

Comment: From the question: "I am not allowed to use built in C++ functions"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is to compare lowercased characters. If you are not allowed to use any built-in functions, you can do it manually.

Since lowercase characters are located in ASCII table starting from 97, and uppercase - starting from 65, you can simply add 32 to the uppercase char to get its lowercase equivalent.

```
char lowerCase(char c)
{
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') // if char is uppercase
        return (char)(c + 32); // return its lowercase equivalent
    else
        return c;
}
```

Then, you can do the following in your `if` condition:

```
if (lowerCase(str.at(i)) > lowerCase(str.at(j)))
```

Note that you shouldn use `lowerCase` only when you compare, but not when you assign.

Here is the [working IDEOne demo](http://ideone.com/L7uYzr).